# Oracle Client 32 bit windows connecting to Oracle Server

Tags: oracle

I have to connect or make service (i don't know what you called exactly),there are table spaces created and i have user name ,password for that,but i don't know how to connect to the Oracle DB,i think there is a procedure by giving credentials and service name,can you please advice me how to do that

Comment: Based on my Oracle Script,they have created table spaces,i think services to be activated from my server where i installed my application and needs to be connected from application.

Comment: i have installed oracle 32 bit client,there is sql developer and sql plus,i need to connect from my pc to oracle server.

Answer (score 1):

You must setup a TNS entry. Google sample tnsnames.ora or use the New Database Connection wizard in SQL Developer. Typically a TNS entry requires your hostname, port (default is 1521) and SID.

Look under your Oracle client home for NETWORK\admin directory

Create tnsnames.ora with an entry that matches your environment. You can also use the Oracle Net Configuration Assistant (Start -> Programs -> OracleHome1 -> Configuration and Migration Tools) on Windows

```
ORA1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.5)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORA1)
    )
  )
```

Then connect with the TNS alias and username and password

Try pinging it first:

```
tnsping ora1
```

SQLPlus

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@ora1
```